# C# - async external process run with redirected output

Tags: c#, process, task

I'm trying run an external .exe in C# using Task.Run and I want to capture output of this app to process it. Here's code:

```
private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    await Task.Run(() => obj.Download());
}
```

Method content:

```
public void Download()
{
    ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        WorkingDirectory = "tools/temp/",
        FileName = "tools/download.exe",
        Arguments = $"{_url} {_path}",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    Process proc = new Process { StartInfo = StartInfo };
    proc.OutputDataReceived += Proc_OutputDataReceived;
    proc.Start();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}

private void Proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // some code    
}
```

The problem is that `OutputDataReceived` event raises after process is completed. Consider following: `download.exe` downloads 4 files, after each file it prints out file name. If I run it using code above, files are downloaded and then 4 events of `OutputDataReceived` are raised. I would like to have event rised immediately after line is printed. Is it possible ?

EDIT:

`download.exe` prints out each file name in new line, and it behaves in the same way without Task.Run

Comment: `download.exe` writes all file names to a single line or each to a new line?

Comment: Accorrding to documentation `OutputDataReceived` should be raised for each output line. Have you tried run this code without `Task.Run`?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: The `Process.OutputDataReceived` event is broadly used, well-tested, and behaves according to the documentation. If you are finding that it seems not to, then either your observation is mistaken, or your assumptions about the external process are mistaken. Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, it's not possible for anyone else to know where your mistake is.